# Same function for multiple target IDs with different event in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this and it's working:

```
function cancelFunction(targetid,e) {
    if (targetid.substring(0,9) == "editinput") {
        if (e.keyCode != 27) {
            return;
        }
        var target = targetid.substring(10);
    }
    else
        var target = targetid.substring(11);
    // DO OTHER STUFF HERE
}
$(\'[id^=editinput]\').keypress(function(e) {
    var targetid= $(this).attr("id");
    cancelFunction(targetid,e);
});
$(\'[id^=canceledit]\').click(function() {
    var targetid= $(this).attr("id");
    cancelFunction(targetid,"");
});
```

What i want to know if it's this possible to merge `keypress` event on `[id^=editinput]` and `click` event on `[id^=canceledit]` in a single call with function declared after that?

I mean something like this (obviously wrong syntax):

```
$((\'[id^=canceledit]\').click)((\'[id^=editinput]\').keypress)(function(e) {
    var targetid = $(this).attr("id");
    if (targetid.substring(0,9) == "editinput") {
        if (e.keyCode != 27) {
            return;
        }
        var target = targetid.substring(10);
    }
    else
        var target = targetid.substring(11);
    // DO OTHER STUFF HERE
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest would probably be to refactor a little

```
function cancelFunction(e) {
    if (this.id.substring(0,9) == "editinput") {
        if (e.keyCode != 27) {
            return;
        }
        var target = this.id.substring(10);
    } else {
        var target = this.id.substring(11);
    }
}

$('[id^=editinput]').on('keypress', cancelFunction);
$('[id^=canceledit]').on('click', cancelFunction);
```

Comment: Ok, this is better than nothing, but does it mean what i'm trying to do (merge all 3 parts) is impossible? (PS: you forgot to move `var targetid = $(this).attr("id");` as first line of cancelFunction)

Comment: I didn't move that line as it's not needed, I'm using `this.id` instead. It's not impossible to merge all three parts, but it will be more complicated and with more code than doing it this way.

Comment: Ok yeah, sorry, didnt notice you changed targetid to `this.id`